# Jquery wrap class not working dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use angular-formly to render element of form but jquery don't work with dynamic content. I find a solution using on:

```
$(document).on("click", "body", function() { 
     $('input').wrap('<div class="test"></div>');
 });
```

This solution help me wrap input by class="test" when I click to body. But I need class="test" always exist when I enter my page, not doing something. Like that in static content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').wrap('<div class="test"></div>');
});
```

What should I do?

Comment: you need to use formly template

Comment: I used className.  But I need wrap some class to edit UI of my page

Comment: Angular formly supports templates...see docs

Comment: I load formly-field from database and each fied is independence. And it packed by <div formly-field></div>. I can't use templates

Comment: well you can't use `$(document).ready` either. You need to do this using the formly api. You could use a directive probably also